# How Could I Recursify this Function?

Tags: python

I wrote a function that compares 2 strings and returns an integer, that represents how many characters they have not only the same, but in the same position. So "cat" and "sat" should return 2, because "at" are the same, and at the same position, but not "cat" and "ecat", which should return 0. I wrote a loop version down below:

```
count = 0
i = 0
while i < min(len(string1), len(string2)):
    if string1[i] == string2[i]:
        count += 1
    i += 1
return count
```

Comment: Asking someone to write code for you from scratch is not well considered here. Try it yourself first and come back if you have a specific problem. There is no shortage of tutorials on recursion out there...

Comment: Please, add some other tags.